# Calculate percentage of matching word

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_pat
(
    id int,
    name varchar(100),
    [address] varchar(500)
);
INSERT INTO tbl_pat VALUES(1,'Jack','Lane 1, 90 Road Street, SL');
INSERT INTO tbl_pat VALUES(2,'Will','SA, Lane 10, Street road');
INSERT INTO tbl_pat VALUES(3,'White','Lane 1 ZIM');
INSERT INTO tbl_pat VALUES(4,'Shaw','Street Road');
INSERT INTO tbl_pat VALUES(5,'Steve','Road Street');
INSERT INTO tbl_pat VALUES(6,'Brown','Nz Road 10');
```

Expected Result:

Search string is : `Street Road`

```
Name    Address                     Percentage
---------------------------------------------
Shaw    Street Road                 100
Steve   Road Street                 100
Will    SA, Lane 10, Street road    20
Jack    Lane 1, 90 Road Street, SL  17
```

Note: The percentage are mentioned on assumption, but the first two should be 100% percent as it has exact match.

I am using PATINDEX for searching the word.

Query: Searching for **Street road**

```
SELECT [Name],[Address] 
FROM tbl_pat 
WHERE PATINDEX('%Street%',[Address])>=1 AND PATINDEX('%Road%',[Address])>=1
```

How to calculate the percentage of the matching word in the single select statement?

Comment: What's the formula for calculating this percentage?

Comment: This will be hard to do accurately without the ability to do full regex searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the percentage calculation expected you have provided
For example Jack, has a match of 2 output 6 words . So I expect its result to be %33

Please test following SQL query where I used [String_Split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx) to split text into words

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'Road Street'

; with tbl as (
select *, count(*) over (partition by id) word_count
from tbl_pat t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(replace(t.address,',',' '), ' ')
where trim([value]) <> ''  
)
select distinct id, [name], word_count, count(search.[value]) over (partition by id),
    convert( decimal(5,2), (100.0 * (count(search.[value]) over (partition by id)) / word_count))
from tbl 
left join (
    select * from STRING_SPLIT(@str, ' ')
) search
    on search.[value] = tbl.[value]
order by id
```

output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here i am using `string_split()` from `SQL Server 2017`. You can replace with any string split function available. Just do a search

It is not perfect but it works for your sample.

```
select  p.id, p.name, p.address, count(k.value) * 100.0 / count(*) as pecentage
from    tbl_pat p
        cross apply string_split(replace([address], ',', ' '), ' ') w
        left join
        (
            select  value
            from    string_split ('Road Street', ' ') 
        ) k on  w.value     = k.value
group by p.id, p.name, p.address
```

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, it will produce correct results if you add filter criteria " where w.value <> '' " to remove empty space returns of split function